# Does german differentiate from 'is eating' and eats?

Tags: verb

I was reading this https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/3088733/When-does-Ihr-go-from-her-to-your-or-their and found the Dog example:

`Mein Hund isst ihr Brot`

And people translate it as `is eating` instead of `eats`

So I was wondering if German language does differentiate these words.

Comment: Does this help? https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18861/why-doesn-t-german-have-a-present-continuous-tense

Comment: @HalvarF Yes, thanks, looks like the term I was searching for is 'present continuous' or 'progressive'

Comment: *Mein Hund isst **ihr** Brot* is either wrong or a [constructio ad sensum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesis) at best. Should be ***sein** Brot* (since *der Hund* is a masculine noun) or *die Hündin* if the dog is female.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: Not necessarily: Die Kinder sind schon satt und haben Salat und Brot übriggelassen, aber mein Hund isst ihr Brot.

Comment: These are Germans, so they do everything. You wanna be exact? Be a German. They generally just use more words and more letters. As an answer to the question what my dog is doing, "My dog is eating" translates as "Mein Hund isst gerade", which translates back as "Right now, my dog is eating", so yeah, they do. Don't forget the second 's' in 'isst', otherwise you end up with a hungry straight dog.